# How to iterate through nxn matrix and store the x co-ord, y co-ord as well as value into an nx3 matrix

Tags: r, loops, matrix

Have written a script that iterates through a matrix and returns the x co-ord and y co-ord of every non-NA value in the matrix. How do i append this code to create another column of the value of each element in the matrix attached to the co-ordinates

```
matrixop = function(m2){
zzz <- NULL

for (i in 1:ncol(m2)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(m2)) {
    if ((is.na(m2[i,j])) == FALSE ){

      }
    zzz <- rbind(zzz,c(i,j))

    }
  }

zzz
}
result = lapply(m1, FUN = matrixop) #m1 being existing nxn matrix
```

actual results were a nx2 matrix with the x co ords in the first column and the y coords in the 2nd column. Trying to get a third column with the value attached to those co ords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of `which` argument `arr.ind` and `cbind` with the values of the matrix seen as a vector. The missing values are removed with `complete.cases`.

```
mat2coord <- function(x){
  d <- which(x == x | is.na(x), arr.ind = TRUE)
  d <- cbind(d, value = c(x))
  d[complete.cases(d), ]
}

m <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 3)
mat2coord(m)
#     row col value
#[1,]   1   1     1
#[2,]   2   1     2
#[3,]   3   1     3
#[4,]   1   2     4
#[5,]   2   2     5
#[6,]   3   2     6


set.seed(1234)
is.na(m) <- sample(6, 2)
mat2coord(m)
#     row col value
#[1,]   1   1     1
#[2,]   3   1     3
#[3,]   2   2     5
#[4,]   3   2     6
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to mess of my matrix. Perhaps this is because my original matrix is not a nx3 matrix. Its a 640x640

Comment: I have just tried with `m2 <- matrix(1:600000, nrow = 300)` and it seems to work as expected.